# Generic Points, Associated Points on $\operatorname{Spec} A$ for an Integral

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm reading section 5.5 from Vakil's FOAG, and I got a bit confused about the associated points of a module $M$. The way he develops this theory, is by first stating some axioms and then proving that they hold. The first axiom states the following:

> (A) The associated primes/points of $M$ are precisely the generic points of irreducible
> components of the support of some element of $M$ (on $\operatorname{Spec} A$).

Now, the very next exercise states the following:

> Suppose $A$ is an integral domain. Show that the
> generic point is the only associated point of $\operatorname{Spec} A$.

This is supposed to be done assuming property A. Now, the exercise itself doesn't state what module $M$ we are working with, as in property (A). Does this mean $M = A$, or do we have to show this for all $A$ modules $M$?
If $M=A$, I think that the exercise is trivial. However, I am unable to show this holds for all $A$ modules $M$. In fact I think that this latter statement is false. Consider $A = \mathbb{Z}$ and $M = \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. As far as I can see, the ideal $(2)$ is in the support of $\overline{1}\in M$, whereas $(3)$ isn't, because $(3)$ doesn't contain $4$, and $4\cdot \overline{1} = 0\in M$ means $\overline{1}$ is $0$ in $M_{(3)}$. This shows that the support of $\overline{1}$ is nonempty, while the it isn't the entirety of $\operatorname{Spec} A$, and this means that $(0)$ can't be the generic point of the support.

I would be very grateful if someone could point out where I am going wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, you are supposed to be thinking about the associated points of $A$ as an $A$-module. The associated points of a scheme $X$ are defined to be the associated points of $\mathcal{O}_X$ (see for instance [Stacks 02IOJ](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02OJ) or other textbooks).

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful!